# NServicebus.host.exe not making my class library runnable in .Net Framework 4.5.1 Visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, nservicebus5

I am using Visual studio 2015 with framework 4.5.1 and NServicebus5.

I am learning NServicebus from the Plural sight videos. It mentions that "To use the host just create a new C# class library and reference the NServiceBus.Host NuGet package. The package will create an example endpoint configuration and sets the NServiceBus.Host.exe as the startup project for the endpoint."

However, in visual studio 2015 there is no "startup project" option available under properties --> Debug tab. Further, no endpoint configuration file being created by NServicebus.host(6.0.0). Hence I cant run my class library.

Can anyone tell me how can I make it work in visual studio 2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the project in the solution explorer with the RH mouse button, then choose *Set As Startup Project* from the menu.

When you have more endpoints (endpoint=project) in the solution, select the solution in solution explorer with RH mouse button, then choose *Set Startup Projects...* from the menu. Click the Multiple Projects radio button.

I haven't checked PluralSight recently, but there was only one video when I was learning. I found the tutorials on the Particular site really good, and there are now loads of good examples on GitHub. Whatever you do, assume you're going to throw away at least one of the projects while you're learning. David Boike's book was handy for getting everything together for deployment.